# Is Node.js the One Allows to Write Cross Platform Applications in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cross-platform

Node.js allows to access IO layer / database and it allows write javascript code in server-side.

I'm just wondering is Node.js the one allows to write cross platform applications  ?

**If yes**,

- How this possible?

Node.js just release on 2009 and has it opens up almost all platforms.

- What is the reason preventing other languages such as C# to get this ability ?

(Apologies if i am mistaking the concept. i'm just stated to learn node.js) (googled)

Comment: I believe -1 for " what is the reason preventing other languages such as C# to get this ability ". I had mono & is not reliable as javascript when it comes to cross platform mobile apps. I heard xamarin (share mono core I believe) which is super expensive. And there is almost-no alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

> How this possible?

It (or library code written in other languages) abstracts operating system specific stuff. Code is then compiled for each platform by the node executable that runs on each platform.

> What is the reason preventing other languages such as C# to get this ability ?

Nothing. That is why C# programs are also able to run cross platform. Here is, for example, a [C# compiler for Linux](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/csharp/).

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS does allow cross platform development, as node abstracts out the system specific functionality into APIs your code can access.

Regarding C#,you can do the same thing, you'll just need to run the code in in something like mono for *nix. However, it's worth noting that .net has gone open source and will soon be compiled natively for other environments (and won't need to run within mono). This also enables you to run it on arm devices as well, such as raspberry pi.

Comment: " Will soon be compiled natively for other environments " well that is  a good news.  i know .net gone open source for years now. i just wonder if there anything to prevent it. thanks